# How can I modify the contents of Project Tasks that are automatically created by confirming a Sales Order in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I have configured a Product to create a Project when a Sales Order is confirmed.

I have added some custom fields to the 'project.task' model and set some values for them in the Project that is being used as a template.

On Sales Order Confirm, when that template Project is (automatically) copied to create a new Project for the Sales Order, I want to modify some values on the component Tasks of the newly created Project. How can I intercept the creation of the Project and its Tasks so that I can modify them?

Comment: Have you tried using create method?

Comment: Check the `sale_project` module, you can override functions that prepare [task](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale_project/models/sale_order.py#L239) or [project](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale_project/models/sale_order.py#L191)  values